# Load next twitter user from Array and get their tweets with blogger.js

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have a javascript array of twitter usernames. I load the first twitter user and their last 5 tweets using blogger.js. I want to have an html button/link for previous and next to load the next/previous username and their tweets replacing the current username and tweets (inner html) by calling blogger.js. How do I iterate over the javascript array using onclick and keep track of where I am in the array? I can call blogger.js from the function I call with onclick. Am I going about this the right way by trying to use jquery? Just looking for some ideas and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you, it seems you just need to keep some state information of what the current index you are at in the array.  In the main script trying something like:

var window.CHIP = {twitterArrayIndex=0}

then with in your event listenter use the CHIP.twitterArrayIndex property:

on your next button
next(){
CHIP.twitterArrayIndex =CHIP.twitterArrayIndex +1;
// lookup value using CHIP.twitterArrayIndex
}

on your previous button
previous(){
CHIP.twitterArrayIndex =CHIP.twitterArrayIndex +1;
// lookup value using CHIP.twitterArrayIndex
}